# Unable to run the Azure Data Factory Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I have a Pipeline in my Develop Branch.

I have two ADF instances which connects to the same branch in the same repository in Azure DevOps.

While I'm able to successfully trigger the pipeline in one of the ADF instance Let's say 'ADF-Test', the other ADF instance Let's say 'ADF-Dev' pipeline is not getting triggered.

Observed that if I rename and publish the pipeline name in the ADF instance 'ADF-Dev' where it was not getting triggered. The pipeline would get triggered in 'ADF-Dev'. And the Pipeline in 'ADF-Test' would not get triggered now.

Comment: Hi， does the pipeline refer to [the Azure DevOps pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/what-is-azure-pipelines?view=azure-devops) or [the Azure Data factory pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipelines-activities?tabs=data-factory)? How did you trigger the pipeline? Can you share some screenshots and detailed steps to better illustrate this issue?

Answer (score 0):

While you can create a trigger and activate it on a branch, the trigger will not run until you publish it from the collaboration branch to the live mode.

To check this, you can switch to live mode, and see if the trigger there is active.
[image: switch to live mode]